# PHP executing second php from the folder where the second php exist using main php

Tags: php

Hi I need to execute a php `child.php` which is on the  folder `child`,  from another php named `parent.php`, and get the out put of `child.php` at `parent.php`. I have the below code but not works as the `child.php` should executed from the folder `child` itself.

How can resolve the issue, like change the directory to `child` and execute the php there and get the output.

```
function execute($filename){
    ob_start();
    include $filename;
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: You can `chdir()` into `child/` before running this `execute()` function then change back (if necessary). http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php Without more details of what is actually in `child.php`, there's not much more to speculate on.

Comment: W.T.F ? û_O could you be a more detailed about `should executed from the folder`

Comment: @Blag `should executed from the folder` because in `child php` I am using  relative path to get some file content, and at the moment I cannot access to change the `child.php`, I can only edit `parent.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to set current working directory to be same as directory executing the script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254000/php-how-to-set-current-working-directory-to-be-same-as-directory-executing-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski)'s comment should be enough to get you going but here is the solution you asked for. Error handling is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
function execute($filename) {
    // store current directory
    $cur_dir = getcwd();
    // change directory to the folder containing $filename
    chdir(dirname($filename));
    ob_start();
    include $filename;
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    // change back to the original working directory
    chdir($cur_dir);
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you could execute it with `exec` and store the result in a variable. I assume that you are running with an unix-like system and calling

> php

on a command line executes the php binary.

```
$file = 'child/child.php';
$fullPath = __DIR__ . '/child/child.php';
$command = 'php ' . $fullPath;
$result = '';
$resultCode = 0;
exec($command, $result, $resultCode);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `system()`

```
function execute($filename){
    ob_start();

    // you may want to get the full path to $filename
    system("php {$filename}");

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

[system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) will execute the command and just output everything, but when used with an output buffer, you can return a string containing the output.

Comment: it only returns the last line of the full output ;)

Comment: wow! i can't believe i've only ever needed to run scripts with more than one line of output. thanks @Paladin76